# Texture mapping on a cylinder

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, texture-mapping

I want to apply an uniform checkerboard texture to a cylinder surface of height `h`, and semiradii `(a,b)`.

I've implemented this shader:

**Vertex shader:**

```
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
float twopi = 6.283185307;
float pi=3.141592654;

float ra = 1.5;
float rb= 1.0;

void main()
{
// Transforming The Vertex
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
// -pi/2 < theta < pi/2
float theta =  (atan2( rb*gl_Vertex.y , ra*gl_Vertex.x)+pi*0.5)/pi;

// Passing The Texture Coordinate Of Texture Unit 0 To The Fragment Shader
    texture_coordinate = vec2(  theta , -(-gl_Vertex.z+0.5) );
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
uniform sampler2D my_color_texture;
void main()
{
    // Sampling The Texture And Passing It To The Frame Buffer
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_color_texture, texture_coordinate);
}
```

while on client side I've specified the following options:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

My texture is a 3768x1200 checkerboard. Now I would like that the texture is applied in order to keep the checkerboard uniform (squares without stretch), but I obtain a correct aspect ratio only in the less curved part of the surface, while on the more curved parts the tiles are stretched.

I would like to understand how to apply the texture without distorting and stretching it, maybe by repeating the texture instead of stretching it.

[image: In the first image the tiles on the less curved part are square]

[image: while where the curvature is higher they are more stretched]

I also have a problem of strange flickering on the borders of the texture, where the two borders intersect, how to solve it (it can be seen in the second image)?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is, you say that the squares are not "square" but that's as you'd expect when you view something at an angle with a perspective view, unless I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: no the perspective is here only to show the shape of the object. What I'm asking is what kind of texture coordinate function should I use in order to prevent the stretching of tiles on the borders of the ellipse.
Should I modify the texture itself?

Comment: Are you trying to map the texture as if it were projected onto the object from the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the texture coordinates to "shrink" it on an object a bit. What you can't do is to parametrize the texture coordinates to scale non-linearly.

So, the options are:

1. Quantize the sampling, modifying texture coordinates to better accomodate the non-circularity (*dynamic, but quality is low when using low-poly tesselation; it's the simplest solution to implement, though*).
2. Use fragment shader to scale texture coordinates non-linearly (*possibly a bit more complicated, but dynamic and giving quite good results, depending on the texture size, filtering used and the texture contents(**!**)*)
3. Modify the texture (*static solution - will work only for given Ra/Rb ratio. However, the quality will be the best possible*).

As to the flickering on the borders, you have to generate mipmaps for your textures.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How is it possible to modify texture coordinates with fragment shader? Should I operate directly on texture_coordinate modifying its `s` components leaving `t` intact?

I've tried to find in GIMP a way to deform the texture, but I can't find a simple way to do it, is there some plugin available for this kind of things?

And what about the mipmaps? I'm using `gluBuild2DMipmaps` but I still have that flickering effect.

Comment: How to modify them? Apply some nonlinear function to them, so yes, modify the `s`, but do it from the fragment shader. Hm, I never used `gluBuild2DMipmaps`. There's a way shown in Red Book to identify if they are initialized correctly. I think you can try this if you aren't sure they're initialized properly. And as to modyfing the texture - It certainly won't be easy, and would probably require some 3D tool rather than purely 2D.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the fragment shader solution, I'm lookig for a tutorial on how to do texture deformation shaders.

Comment: ah ok, it's simple, I've understood how to operate on u,v texture coordinates directly...for example something like:

`gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_color_texture, vec2(asin(texture_coordinate.x),texture_coordinate.y) );`

Comment: Exactly ;) well, I thought you knew that at once. Good that it's working